# How to connect to Azure SQL sever from Azure AKS cluster via private endpoint

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-aks, azure-mysql-database

In my Azure environment I have private SQL Server. To access SQL Server and databases I use a private endpoint. When I connect to SQL from VM in the same Virtual Network I have no problem. I have AKS in the same Virtual Network I try to connect to the database from pod but Kubernetes DNS didn't resolve SQL Server FQDN correctly. DNS name resolved to external IP but private SQL didn't have external access.

This is example how SQL Server resolved from VM:

```
nslookup *****************.database.windows.net
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*****************.database.windows.net  canonical name = *****************.privatelink.database.windows.net.
Name:   *****************.privatelink.database.windows.net
Address: 172.0.8.4
```

This is correct address to Private Endpoint

And how it resolve from pod in AKS cluster:

```
kubectl exec -it dnsutils -- nslookup *****************.database.windows.net

Server:     10.0.0.10
Address:    10.0.0.10#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*****************.database.windows.net  canonical name = *****************.privatelink.database.windows.net.
*****************.privatelink.database.windows.net  canonical name = dataslice6.******.database.windows.net.
dataslice6.******.database.windows.net  canonical name = dataslice6*******.trafficmanager.net.
dataslice6*******.trafficmanager.net    canonical name = cr5.******-a.control.database.windows.net.
Name:   cr5.*******-a.control.database.windows.net
Address: 40.78.225.32
```

How I can set connection pods from AKS to SQL Private Endpoint?

Comment: You are accessing from a subnet in your AKS cluster, maybe you should check docker bridge address, or create a new vnet for AKS and connect both vnets via peering.

Comment: Does your VM have a local DNS configuration or does it lean on the default DNS servers set up on your vnet? Are you using default Microsoft DNS servers or have something of your own? Do you have a private DNS zone created for for privatelink.database.windows.net and linked to your vnet?

Answer (score 2):

Create a [**firewall rule**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/single-server/concepts-firewall-rules#connecting-from-azure) on the ***Azure DB Server*** with a range of IP addresses of the ***AKS Cluster nodes.***

Create a [**VNet Rule**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/single-server/concepts-data-access-and-security-vnet) on the Azure DB Server that ***allows access*** from the subnet to the ***AKS nodes***. This is used in `Microsoft.Sql` VNet Service Endpoint enabled on the cluster subnet.

If Azure SQL Database is restricted to allow only ***private access***, we can use cross-region private endpoints via [**Azure Private Link for the Azure SQL**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/private-endpoint-overview?view=azuresql) database or in ***region private endpoint*** with Azure Global [**VNet-peering**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-peering-overview).

To connect to AKS from SQL Private Endpoint, we will use [**VNet Peering**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/private-endpoint-overview?view=azuresql) with Azure SQL Database Private Link.

For more in **detail**, please **refer** below links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/command-invoke

https://arsenvlad.medium.com/aks-workload-accessing-azure-sql-database-in-another-region-cb6fb30545e4

https://argonsys.com/microsoft-cloud/library/private-aks-and-acr-using-private-endpoint-part-1-2/

https://blog.crossplane.io/azure-secure-connectivity-for-aks-azure-db/

Answer (score 0):

I guess your SQL server's private IP is falling in the docker bridge's CIDR range which is found in the Networking menu in your AKS cluster. If it falls in the range, then docker won't allow the request to go out of docker network.